# PS4 controller too touchy on the arduino RC car i built

Tags: arduino-uno

I recently built an RC car from scratch and I am using a PS4 controller to control it.  I have an ESC of course but my problem is I barely touch the joystick and the motor is going so fast I cannot control the car. Here is the code and any help would be much appreciated.

```
/*
 Example sketch for the PS4 Bluetooth library - developed by Kristian Lauszus
 For more information visit my blog: http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/ or
 send me an e-mail:  kristianl@tkjelectronics.com
 */

#include <PS4BT.h>
#include <usbhub.h>
#include <Servo.h>

// Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#endif

USB Usb;
//USBHub Hub1(&Usb); // Some dongles have a hub inside
BTD Btd(&Usb); // You have to create the Bluetooth Dongle instance like so
Servo servo1;  //Steering Servo
Servo servo2;  //DC Motor

/* You can create the instance of the PS4BT class in two ways */
// This will start an inquiry and then pair with the PS4 controller - you only have to do this once
// You will need to hold down the PS and Share button at the same time, the PS4 controller will then start to blink rapidly indicating that it is in paring mode
PS4BT PS4(&Btd, PAIR);

// After that you can simply create the instance like so and then press the PS button on the device
//PS4BT PS4(&Btd);

bool printAngle, printTouch;
uint8_t oldL2Value, oldR2Value;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
  while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
    while (1); // Halt
  }
  Serial.print(F("\r\nPS4 Bluetooth Library Started"));

  pinMode (3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (5, OUTPUT);
  servo1.attach (3);
  servo2.attach (5);
}
void loop() {
  Usb.Task();

  if (PS4.connected()) {

    {
    servo1.write(map(PS4.getAnalogHat(RightHatX), 0, 255, 50, 0)); 
       //map values from the x-axis of the right analog stick
    servo2.write(map(PS4.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY), 0, 255, 0, 180));
       //map values from the y-axis of the left analog stick
    }}

    else

    {
      servo1.write (25);  // set servo motor to 0 point
      servo2.write (90);  // Turn DC motor off 
    }
```